# 'Action' attribute of the dash_bootstrap_components 'form'

Tags: python, forms, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm trying to build a small form with `dash` and `dash-bootstrap-components`, but I can't figure out how to use the ['action' attribute](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/form/) of the form.

Or, rather, I'm trying to save the data that the user inputs into the form to the Postgres DB, and the `action` attribute seems to be the way to do that, but I wasn't able to find any examples on how to use it.

Did anybody have experience building forms with DBC?

EDIT my current solution is (in a simplified form):

```
def handle_submit(n_submit, e, pass): 
    username = e.split('@') 
    pg = pd.DataFrame(e, username, pass) 
    if n_submit:
       pg.to_sql("table", con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
       return 'success'
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `action` endpoint isn't used

> prevent_default_on_submit (boolean; default True): The form calls preventDefault on submit events. If you want form data to be posted to the endpoint specified by action on submit events, set prevent_default_on_submit to False. Defaults to True.

Based on your question it seems you just want to do something on submit and have no need for the `action`. In this case you can do something like this:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

form = dbc.Form(
    id="form",
    children=[
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Email", className="mr-2"),
                dbc.Input(id="email", type="email", placeholder="Enter email"),
            ],
            className="mr-3",
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Password", className="mr-2"),
                dbc.Input(id="password", type="password", placeholder="Enter password"),
            ],
            className="mr-3",
        ),
        dbc.Button("Submit", color="primary"),
    ],
    inline=True,
)

app.layout = html.Div([form, html.Div(id="output")])


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("form", "n_submit"),
    State("email", "value"),
    State("password", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def handle_submit(n_submit, email, password):
    # Do stuff...
    return n_submit


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

*`n_submit` is returned in the callback above in order to show that the submit action works, but you probably want to change this to something else according to your needs.*

**Update**

Based on your edit you could change the callback to something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("form", "n_submit"),
    State("email", "value"),
    State("password", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def handle_submit(n_submit, email, password):
    username = email.split("@")
    pg = pd.DataFrame(
        {"email": [email], "username": [username], "password": [password]}
    )
    if n_submit:
        pg.to_sql("table", con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
        return "success"
    return ""
```

I've changed the way the DataFrame is constructed and the variable names. `pass` is a reserved keyword so I wouldn't use that as a parameter name. I've also added a default return statement. Not really necessary here as `prevent_initial_call` is set to `True`, but it shows how you could account for the case that `n_submit` were to evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Bas, thank you for your input. Can you please do me a favor and complete your example so that the function would take the values from the input fields and save them to a database?
Right now I have something like:
```def handle_submit(n_submit, e, pass):
username = e.split('@')
pg = pd.DataFrame(e, username, pass)
if n_submit:
  pg.to_sql("table", con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
  return 'success'```
but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added this piece of code into the body of the problem under `EDIT` for better visibility

Comment: thank you again very much. I managed to solve my issue with your advice.